# Pass variable as parameter to onclick function using double and single quotes in .append JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a variable as a parameter to onClick function using JQuery append. as the number of rows are uncertain I am using $.each to add a button at the end of each row which when clicked will edit that row.
So to get that row i am passing the id of that row to the Onclick function in a button, I am confused with the quotes as the function is not working.

Here is the code

```
$.each(result, function (key, item) {
                $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name + "</td> <td>" + item.type + "</td> <td>" + item.weight + "</td> <td>" + item.birthday + "</td> <td>" + item.hasHorns + "</td><td><input class='editR' id='" + item.id + "' type='button' value='EDIT' onclick='editRow('" + item.id + "')'/> </td> </tr>");
            });
```

FUNCTION

```
function editRow(eid) {

    $("#table1").empty();
    //var eid = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(this);
    $.getJSON(uri + "GetByID/" + eid, function (data) {
        $("#headerType").replaceWith("<h2>Edit Animal</h2>");
        $("#table1").append("<tr><td><h4>ID</h4></td> <td><h4>Name</h4></td> <td><h4>Type</h4></td> <td><h4>Weight</h4></td> <td><h4>Birthday</h4></td> <td><h4>Has Horns</h4></td></tr>");
        $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td> <td>" + data.type + "</td> <td>" + data.weight + "</td> <td>" + data.birthday + "</td> <td>" + data.hasHorns + "</td> </tr>");
    });
}
```

RESULT on Browser Inspect element (Sorry i cannot post pics as it needs 10 impoession)

```
<input class="editR" id="1" type="button" value="EDIT" onclick="editRow(" 1')'="">
```

everything works but nothing happens on click

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```
  onclick=\"editRow('" + item.id + "')\"/>
```